# Breaking join between two vertices in Box2D AndEngine

Tags: android, box2d, andengine

How to destroy revolute joint dynamically in Box2D Extension of AndEngine.
I would really appreciate the correct and explanatory answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `createJoint(jointDef)` returns a Joint object which you can later use to destroy the joint: `mPhysicsWorld.destroyJoint(revoluteJointdef)`
Source: [http://www.andengine.org/forums/physics-box2d-extension/destroy-revolutejointdef-t5979.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20140830093816/http://www.andengine.org/forums/physics-box2d-extension/destroy-revolutejointdef-t5979.html)

Comment: Can we get an update here, and possibly more than just a link?

Comment: @LeMotJuiced Oh dear, younger me wrote some shitty answers, totally not up to the current standards :-/ What do you need the update for BTW? It seems that AndEngine has been dormant for some 10 years, so I'm not sure if a better answer would be useful to anyone.

Comment: But since it didn't allow me to edit just the link since the answer is too short and would not pass validation, I updated it a bit nevertheless.